# SQL Server 2012 stored procedure runs slow

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a SQL Server stored procedure and it runs fine on SQL Server 2008 R2.

When I try to run it on SQL Server 2012, it takes very very long time to run.

But if I create local variables inside the stored procedure and copy the values of input parameters into those local variables and use them instead of input parameters, query runs and returns result faster than on SQL Server 2008 R2 database (please note both 2008 R2 and 2012 servers run on the same box).

Could you please shed some light on what is going on here?

Comment: Should be on DBA.se, as this is not a programming question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By creating local variables and rebinding values you disable **[parameter sniffing](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/parameter-sniffing/)**:

> Parameter sniffing is the process whereby  SQL Server creates an
> optimal plan for a stored procedure by using the calling parameters
> that are passed the first time a stored procedure is executed
>
> Every subsequent call to the same store procedure with the same parameters will also get an optimal plan, **whereas calls with different parameter values may not always get an optimal plan**

Run slows:

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[DisplayBillingInfo]
  @BeginDate DATETIME,
  @EndDate DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT BillingDate, BillingAmt
  FROM BillingInfo
  WHERE BillingDate between @StartDate AND @StopDate; 
END
```

Run fast (because it has to calculate new execution plan each time):

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[DisplayBillingInfo]
  @BeginDate DATETIME,
  @EndDate DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = @BeginDate;
  DECLARE @StopDate DATETIME = @EndDate;

  SELECT BillingDate, BillingAmt
  FROM BillingInfo
  WHERE BillingDate between @StartDate AND @StopDate; 
END
```

The case is SQL Server optimizer cannot reuse cached plan and evaluate it each time.

This is the same as you use `WITH RECOMPILE`:

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[DisplayBillingInfo]
  @BeginDate DATETIME,
  @EndDate DATETIME
WITH RECOMPILE
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT BillingDate, BillingAmt
  FROM BillingInfo
  WHERE BillingDate between @StartDate AND @StopDate; 
END
```

using query hint:

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[DisplayBillingInfo]
  @BeginDate DATETIME,
  @EndDate DATETIME
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT BillingDate, BillingAmt
  FROM BillingInfo
  WHERE BillingDate between @StartDate AND @StopDate
  OPTION(RECOMPILE);
  -- OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (@StartDate UNKNOWN, @StopDate UNKNOWN))
END
```

Comment: Thank You @lad2025. You are absolutely right on what I had to do to make the query run fast on SQL Server 2012.

But why only on SQL server 2012?  Why the procedure runs fine on SQL server 2008?

Comment: @kudlur Maybe in SQL Server 2008 you have cached optimal plan and provide parameters that works with it well. Can you try use different parameter to recreate the issue. Also if you are testing clear buffer first

Comment: SQL server 2008 R2 is production, and has never encountered slowness issue so far.
On SQL server 2012 the very first execution of the stored proc gave problem. Dropping and recreating did not solve the issue. Recompile option did not work either.

Comment: @kudlur Try `SELECT ... FROM ... OPTION(RECOMPILE)` instead of `WITH RECOMPILE`

Comment: @kudlur If it is sniffing the same parameter values as you are executing with (first run) and you still get a bad plan you probably need to update statistics.

Comment: Alternatively, the SQl server 2012 server may be missing some indexes thus creating a more inefficient plan even with the same parameters.

Comment: @smith, We updated statistics, rebuilt indexes, and procedure cache was also cleared for the database in question. Nothing helped. Running the procedure with same parameter values  multiple times would always take same amount of time (around 30 secs). But assignment of  parameter values to local variables would run in less than a second..